# Subspaces and span?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $S$ be the subspace spanned by $(\text{u}_1, \text{u}_2, ... , \text{u}_m)$. Then, $S$ is the smallest subspace containing $(\text{u}_1, \text{u}_2, ... , \text{u}_m)$ in the sense that if $S_2$ is any other subspace containing $(\text{u}_1, \text{u}_2, ... , \text{u}_m)$, then $S \subseteq S_2$.

Could someone please explain why the above statement is true? I don't have any work to show, because I have no clue how to even approach the problem. Thanks.

**Definition of "Subspace Spanned By":** Let $(\text{u}_1, \text{u}_2, ... , \text{u}_m)$ be a set of vectors. The subspace spanned by $(\text{u}_1, \text{u}_2, ... , \text{u}_m)$ is defined to be the set of vectors $A$ such that if $v \in A$, $$v = \sum_{i = 1}^{m} a_i\text{u}_i$$

for some scalars $(a_1, a_2,..., a_i)$

Comment: That could be the definition of "the subspace spanned by". Is it? Or have you another definition (which?) and shall prove that characterisation?

Comment: @DanielFischer I added in the definition I am using :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $S_2$ is another subspace containing $(u_1, \dotsc, u_m)$.  Choose some element $v \in \text{span}(u_1, \dotsc, u_m)$.  Then
$$ v = a_1 u_1 + \dotsb + a_m u_m $$
for appropriate scalars $a_i$.  Since $u_i \in S_2$ for each $i$, we must have $a_i u_i \in S_2$ for each $i$, and hence $v \in S_2$. This implies $\text{span}(u_1, \dotsc, u_m) \subseteq S_2$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you :)